# Open local files on Safari

Tags: safari

I would like to know if there is a way (i.e. plugin) to open local files on Safari as i am used to do with FF or IE. Suggestions anyone?

**EDIT:** I do not want to open the file using "Open->File", but i want my CMS to be able to open local files from a CMS-context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By CMS open local files, I presume you mean that you want the CMS to supply a file system type URI to the browser, that is compatible with all the browsers in your environment.

If that is the case then what Chopper3 said should work.

If you really want the CMS to open files - i.e. serve up URLs to locally stored files, then you will have a bigger challenge, as this may well be different depending on where the browser is running - e.g. same machine as CMS/Web Server or other machines.

Answer (score 3):

file:// is considered a security threat by some and as a result will not work in some browsers. In Safari a manually typed link to file:///Users/me/file.jpg will work but it will not work in a link tag in your code.

Answer (score 2):

That said, it's just `file:///{drive letter}:/{path}/{filename}` in the url bar.